# What's the difference between ssh and openssh packages?

Tags: package-management, ssh, openssh

I am setting up a LAMP server and want to use SSH. I saw a command for `sudo apt-get install ssh` and wondered if it was the same thing as openssh?

If I was to now do a apt-get install openssh would I have two different versions of ssh on my machine?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok... Simple:  Let's ask the package manager `aptitude search ssh`.  You will get a rather large output, but I'll pick a few for you:

```
i A openssh-client                  - secure shell (SSH) client, for secure acce
p   openssh-server                  - secure shell (SSH) server, for secure acce
p   ssh                             - secure shell client and server (metapackag
v   ssh-client                      -                          
v   ssh-server                      -
```

That is my desktop and it doesn't have a ssh server. It does have a client.  See the first letter?  Here you see three different ones: `i`, `p` and `v`.  They stand for `installed`, `purged` and `virtual`.  Installed is obvious, the program is there.  `purged` means not installed, if you remove a program completely, it is called purging and that is indistinguishable from a program that has never been installed.  Finally, there is `virtual`.  Those are not real packages but point to one or more packages to be installed.

As you can see in the description `ssh` is a normal package which will install the client and the server.  Let's ask the package manager what exactly it means:  `aptitude show ssh`, which will give you:

```
Package: ssh                             
State: not installed
Version: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 29,7 k
Depends: openssh-client (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8), openssh-server (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8)
Description: secure shell client and server (metapackage)
 This metapackage is a convenient way to install both the OpenSSH client and the OpenSSH server. It provides nothing in and of itself, so you
 may remove it if nothing depends on it.
Homepage: http://www.openssh.org/
```

The description is pretty straightforward, but you can gather more information from it than just the description.  There is a line starting with `Depends`.  That means, "in order to install this package the following packages must also be installed".  Now look at that: it installs both openssh-client and openssh-server.

So, what is the difference?  `aptitude install openssh-server` will install only, and only `openssh-server`.  `aptitude install ssh` will both install `openssh-server` and `openssh-client`, but unless you have a very strange configuration, you almost certainly already have `openssh-client`.

So practically?  There is no difference... but you got to learn something about packages today.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer jawtheshark. I see when I run "aptitude" that it is not currently installed...must not be a default program that is installed with Ubuntu?

Comment: It's not, indeed.  Many instructions tell you to use `apt-get` which is totally fine.  I prefer `aptitude` as it integrates a bunch of functionality from the different apt-* programs.  For example, the search command needs to be done with `apt-cache` instead of `apt-get`.   The new kid on the block is  `apt`, which is included by default in 16.04LTS

Comment: Historically (from memory, others can correct me), it's `dpkg`, `apt-get` (and many other tools starting with `apt-`), `aptitude` and now `apt`.  In order, `dpkg` being the oldest, and `apt`the newest.

Comment: @jb61264 You should probably accept this answer as it completely answers your question. I doubt you can get anything better than this. :)

Comment: But if you install `ssh` and later remove `ssh` will it also remove `openssh-client` which was already installed automatically before you installed `ssh`?

Comment: If it was already there, it shouldn't be uninstalled, no.